# Log4j to kestrel

Tags: logging, log4j, kestrel

We are running a Java Project that produces a lot of log messages using log4j, which are currently stored in normal files on the filesystem. Because the project runs on several servers we would prefer a single instance to send the logs to until further processing. Because we are already running the JVM on the servers, we were thinking about using [kestrel](https://github.com/robey/kestrel) for this.

Being new to both log4j and kestrel, we are wondering if there is a way to configure log4j so that it writes directly to the kestrel installed on the same server?

Answer (score 2):

For your use case (putting logs in a centralized location) I would use something other than Kestrel.

[Kafka](http://incubator.apache.org/kafka/quickstart.html) is an Apache incubator project that originated at Linkedin. Kafka has an awesome Log4j appender where you just specify the appender in your log4j.properties file.

Flume is another great piece of software for collecting logs. Where Kafka is like a message queue where you read log lines off the queue and process them, Flume will just dump your logs on a central server or in S3 or Hadoop. Flume also has a log4j appender.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give both a try and report afterwards.